# Recursive query in Hive/IBM DataStage

Tags: recursion, hive, datastage, dynamicquery

I'm new in Hive and Datastage development. I'm trying to do a recursive query like we can do in Orcale with connect by or with clause, but Hive doesn't support recursive queries. Is there any way to do this in Hive? Or to do the logic through IBM datastage job?

Many thanks,

Priscila Ferreira

Comment: Can you give some examples of what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: So, I have a table with parent-child relationship and I need to know for specific parent which childrens are below him. Graphically, I have a tree. But I never know until which level the hierarchy goes. For that reason, i can't do a loop and i would need the recursivity.